# Few month old Stamped concrete patio crumbling in a few areas

Tags: concrete

had a stamped concrete patio poured back in may. There are areas around the stamped line that look kind of crumbly dry.. like the stamp was lifted but the area wasnt smoothed. Some areas are starting to chip away. I have been having trouble getting a hold of the guy who did it (no surprise). I did finally get a hold of him and he said he would be out today but never showed.

Below are some pictures but is there anything i can just do to be done with it? I dont feel like getting involved with a small claims court over this but if it's going to get worse then i surely will. It almost looks like it needs to be sanded smooth and then more sealer applied.

Pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've been considering a stamped concrete patio and have been watching a lot of videos.  Do you happen to know whether the concrete guy used powdered or liquid release agent?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the powdered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maybe the concrete was allowed to cure too long before stamping and had started to harden excessively. You could grind the loose areas down, but they'll have a different appearance from the textured areas.

If it was my patio, and I wasn't interested in pursuing satisfaction from the mason, I'd probably find an epoxy sealer that's designed for concrete and try to bandage it up as well as possible without altering the appearance too much. You may be able to tint the epoxy to match, and then fill the cracks in the crumbed areas to bond them together.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot come spring. So is it better to just spot treat with the epoxy, rather than epoxying the whole thing? If the whole thing should be epoxied, should I remove the old sealer? Or leave it since it was just put on? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by sealing the cracks minimally and see how that goes. From there it depends on the products you choose.

Comment: Okay, last follow up question. When applying, so it blends in best with the acrylic sealer, can I just brush it on evenly with a foam brush, or will special care need to be taken to make sure it blends properly.

Comment: I'd try dabbing judiciously and see where that gets you. Use your best judgement from there.